# How do we display the data got from axios in a table in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, axios, element-ui

I am new to Vuejs and I came across an issue while displaying the data/user information retrieved from the API endpoints using axios. Following is the code to retrieve the data from the api endpoints:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {

  data(){
        return{
            userInfo: []
        };
    },

  created(){
      this.getInfo();
  },

  methods:{
    getInfo(){
        axios.get('http://URL')
        .then(response => this.userInfo = response.data)
        .catch(error => this.userInfo = error.data);
    },      
  }  
}
```

So, I do get the data from the api endpoint into userInfo (which is an array - username, userId, etc). How do I display the contents of the userInfo (which is an array) in the table form in the template section of the vuejs?

If below is a schema of the table I have created in the template (html part) of vuejs? How do I populate the rows with the data from teh userInfo got from the api endpoints?

```html
<el-table>
  <el-table-column min-width="50" type="index"></el-table-column>
  <el-table-column min-width="150" label="Name"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

The above code simply creates a column, but how do I populate it with the rows with the data got in userInfo? UserInfo has the usernames of the users. And I want to populate the rows of the column "Name" with username in userInfo.

I am able to display the user names as a list of usernames on the UI with tht following code:

```html
<ul id="dsiplaying">
    <li v-for="user in userInfo" :key="userInfo.id">{{user.username}}
</li></ul>
```

but, how do I populate the username in table form user the name column created above?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `<el-table>` come from? Is that ElementUI or something else? If it's Element, have you tried looking at the example in the [documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)?

Answer (score 3):

Element UI is, in my opinion, very difficult to use due to its overly cumbersome [documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table) but if you must...

```html
<el-table :data="userInfo"> <!--  bind the table's "data" prop to your "userInfo" array -->

  <!-- this is an index column, ie row number starting from "1" -->
  <el-table-column type="index" min-width="50"></el-table-column>

  <!-- this column shows the "id" property of your objects -->
  <el-table-column prop="id" label="ID"></el-table-column>

  <!-- this column shows the "username" property of your objects -->
  <el-table-column prop="username" label="Username"></el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

This will initially render nothing while your `userInfo` array is empty but once the Axios request completes and updates your array, the table will be populated with data.

---

If you just wanted to show your data in a plain old HTML table, you would use something like this

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(user, index) in userInfo" :key="user.id">
      <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The above code worked smoothly for me.